# MPMoviePlayerController generate thumbnail of local video file and store it

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, thumbnails

I'm making an app that downloads movies from the server and stores them localy in the NSDocumentDirectory.

This works fine.

I want to add a thumbnail generated from each movie in front of the name in each cell.

**My problem:**

How can I generate a thumbnail from a movie after it is downloaded (so instantly, without having to play the movie first)? I want to store the thumbnails with the same name of the movie as a jpg in the NSDocumentDirectory.

**My guess**

-download movie and store it in NSDocumentDirectory (works)

-somehow load the movie in the MPMoviePlayerController's memory (don't know how)

-when loaded in memory, generate thumbnail with thumbnailImageAtTime (MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame) (should work)

-store it (should work)

If anyone could help me...

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>   


-(UIImage*)getFirstFrameFromVideoFile:(NSString*)sourceFilePath {
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sourceFilePath];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
//Player autoplays audio on init
[player stop];
[player release];
return thumbnail;
}
```

Other tasks you know already.

Comment: This does not work. I think the problem is that the movie must first be loaded into the memory. Though I don't know how to do that.

Comment: **sourceFilePath** is the NSDocumentDirectory path where physically the video file is stored.

Comment: I'm doing everyhting right, though the thumbnail image returned (data lenght) is 0, so no thumbnail is being created...

Comment: What is the full nslog of **sourceFilePath**? Does it contain extension (.mov or .mp4) at the end?

Comment: I've added some more info in an answer above

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using MPMoviePlayer works... but you must be sure that you do not have another movie player playing elsewhere in your app (even the UIWebView plug-in...) or you will get in trouble.
I do this way:

```
UIImage *thumbnail = nil;
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathname];
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
NSError *error = nil;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(3, 1); // 3/1 = 3 second(s)
CGImageRef imgRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:nil error:&error];
if (error != nil)
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", self, error);
thumbnail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
CGImageRelease(imgRef);
```

Hope this might help

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use which should generate the thumbnail
(added a big uiimageview for testing, works when I load a local image in it)

```
NSString *path;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"snijtechniekendir/videos"];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSLog(@"video url: %@", videoURL);

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

    UIImageView *cellimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2 , 400, 400)];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellimage];
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail);
    NSLog(@"lenght of video thumb: %@", [imgData length]);
    [self.view addSubview:cellimage];
    [cellimage setImage:thumbnail];
```

This is the log for one video file

```
video url: file://localhost/Users/Home/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/78C165BB-75A9-46A2-A257-469F8652A665/Documents/snijtechniekendir/videos/snijtechniek%2520brunoise.mp4

lenght of video thumb: (null)
```